# POST an image to django backend via Postman

Tags: django, postman

I m not able to upload an image to the backend using via post request
i m using django this is my model :

```js
class Upload(models.Model):
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True)
   


    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

this is my view :

```js
@csrf_exempt
def image_list(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        images=Upload.objects.all()
        serializers=ImageSerializer(images,many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializers.data,safe=False)

    elif request.method=='POST':
        data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer=ImageSerializer(data=data, required=False)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data,status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors,status=400)
```

and this is my serializer, i think the problem is in the isValid but i m really new and i can't seem to figure it out please help me.

```js
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Upload



class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Upload
        fields=['id','image_file']
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse the data give the file directly. Try this:

```
serializer=ImageSerializer(data=request.FILES['image'], required=False)
```

'image' is the key in which you are sending the image as value from the postman.
Try this and also please share the exact error you are getting it this doesn't help and also on the future for other questions.

Comment: thank you for helping , this is the error i m getting : {
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got InMemoryUploadedFile."
    ]
} after i changed my code as you suggested  and stopped using the parser i used to form data to import the image

Comment: no that's the error i m getting now after changing the code as you suggested

Comment: Ok this is a weird error. Can you share your from views.py and also can you check once which line is giving this error? Also if the problem is solved can you inform what you did.

Comment: Can you share new code from views.py function and also will you check which line is giving this error?